# Закрытие формы Tkinter python

Tags: python, время, tkinter

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос для python 2.7, у меня есть форма gui(библиотека Tkinter) которая выводит текст, как сделать так, что бы через предположим 20 секунд она сама закрывалась.

Пример формы:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import*
inf = "Hello world"
app = Tk()
app.title("title")
app.geometry("450x200+100+0")
label1 = Label(text=inf)
label1.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [What is the difference between root.destroy() and root.quit()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307464/what-is-the-difference-between-root-destroy-and-root-quit)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы выйти из GUI, завершив mainloop, через 20 секунд:

```
app.after(20000, app.destroy)
```